# SQL Server 2005 connection with visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I'm doing my project in Visual Studio 2010 and using SQL Server 2005 as my backend.

In SQL Server 2005 I created a table named `dbo.Registration`. It contains a column `UsedFileSize`. I need to show the data in the `UsedFileSize` column on an aspx page.

How do I connect the table column `UsedFileSize`?

I wrote this code and it shows error named DataRow Bind was not found. How to code for this?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UsedFileSize">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UsedFileSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UsedFileSize") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUsedFileSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UsedFileSize") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ControlStyle Width="75px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this:

```
Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UsedFileSize") %>'
```